# Working with high polycounts?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, performance

I'm importing meshes to do some retopologisation on but blender just can't handle it without me having some sort of quadro card. Do I have to use mudbox or something similar to do work with such poly counts?

Comment: Try enabling vertex buffer objects (VBOs) in the preferences and see if that helps

Comment: Be specific please, how many polys and more importantly how many objects are we talking about?

Comment: :o VBOs works! Thankyou! Never seen that feature in all my years o' blender :D

Comment: Also jerryno I was trying to look about a 4.6 million poly object, just one, but VBOs works nicely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

As of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBc402a379a23af71aa5c21566967b75ab5c869e01) (will be in 2.77) VBOs are always enabled and the option has been removed from the user preferences.

---

Enabling VBOs ([Vertex Buffer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object)) can often help performance with really high poly objects.

Enable it in *User Preferences > System*:

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to turn this answer into a general resource for things you can do to help handle craploads of geometry (e.g. disable double sided faces, using local view, instancing...), unless a thread like that already exists?

Comment: I just wish it was enabled by default anyway, but yeah it's good to know about too!

Comment: @JamesF Enabling it be default was discussed, but in the end it was decided not to because some drivers/gpus have issues with it.

Comment: I don't see this option in 2.77 daily build, was it removed? It's still present in 2.76.

Comment: @jubi Yes. [As of 2.77 this option is always on](https://developer.blender.org/rBc402a379a23af71aa5c21566967b75ab5c869e01)